# How to format gcloud compute instances list output to excel format

Tags: linux, shell, csv, awk, sed

Tried various approaches, but nearest to working one:

1. Replace multiple spaces with single one
2. Replace commas(,) in INTERNAL_IP column with Pipe(|)
3. Remove 4th cloumn (PREEMPTIBLE) as it was causing IPs in INTERNAL_IP cloumn shift under it.
4. Replace space with comma(,) to prepare a csv file.

But did not work. Gets messed up at PREEMPTIBLE cloumn.

```
    gcloud compute instances list > file1 
    
    tr -s " " < file1 > file2 // to replace multiple spaces with single one
    
    sed s/\,/\|/g file2 > file3 // to replace , with pipe
    
    awk '{$4=""; print $0}' file3 // to remove 4th column
    
    sed -e 's/\s\+/,/g' file3 > final.csv
```

Output of `gcloud compute instances list` command:
[image: Output of gcloud compute instances list command:]

Expected format:
[image: Expected format]

Any help or suggestion is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Edit:
Attached sample input and expected output files:

[sample_input.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vqlq5aWachiYztGZQ3up0pRzb_JdIHfm/view?usp=sharing)

[expected_output.xlsx](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_DOJNdnzM52PWPtbGbLpW6jSU8NeFJKu/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please paste output as text instead of image

Comment: If you post a [mcve] with concise, testable **textual** sample input and expected output then we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

csv [format](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/formats) is supported in gcloud CLI so everything you are doing can be done without sed/awk maybe with `| tail -n +2` if you want to skip the column header :

```
gcloud compute instances list --format="csv(NAME,ZONE,MACHINE_TYPE,PREEMPTIBLE,INTERNAL_IP,EXTERNAL_IP,STATUS)" > final.csv
```

Or if you wanted to do something with the data in your bash script:

```
while IFS="," read -r NAME ZONE MACHINE_TYPE PREMPTIBLE INTERNAL_IP EXTERNAL_IP STATUS
do
    echo "NAME=$NAME ZONE=$ZONE MACHINE_TYPE=$MACHINE_TYPE PREMPTIBLE=$PREMPTIBLE INTERNAL_IP=$INTERNAL_IP EXTERNAL_IP=$EXTERNAL_IP STATUS=$STATUS"
done < <(gcloud compute instances list --format="csv(NAME,ZONE,MACHINE_TYPE,PREEMPTIBLE,INTERNAL_IP,EXTERNAL_IP,STATUS)" | tail -n +2 | awk ' BEGIN {print "NAME,ZONE,MACHINE_TYPE,PREMPTIBLE,INTERNAL_IP,EXTERNAL_IP,STATUS"} {print $1","$2","$3","" "","$4","" "","$5}' )
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on attached files sample input & expected output i have made following change :

1. Some of the instances for multiple internal IPs and they are
   separated by ",". I have replaced that "," with "-" using **sed
   's/,/-/g'** to aviod conflicts with other fields as we are
   generating a CSV.
2. Displaying $4 & $6 in 5th & 7th columns so that they will be aligned
   with Column Headers *Internal IP Address* and *Status*

   cat command_output.txt | grep -v 'NAME' | sed 's/,/-/g' |  awk ' BEGIN {print "NAME,ZONE,MACHINE_TYPE,PREMPTIBLE,INTERNAL_IP,EXTERNAL_IP,STATUS"} {print $1","$2","$3","" "","$4","" "","$5}'

Comment: Not sure about the rest but `grep -v 'foo' | awk '{bar}'` = `awk '!/foo/{bar}'` and `"" ""` = `""`.

Comment: @confused genius Thank you very much for the answer. The sample file you considered have values at 4th and 6th column, but the command output does not.

I have attached sample input file and expected output file, can you please consider them?

Comment: @confused genius, it worked like charm. Thank you! :-)