# How to format output of gcloud command, Debian

Tags: google-cloud-platform, debian, gcloud

I'm currently working through some GCP training courses via https://www.cloudskillsboost.google/ and seeing some differences in my output versus the documentation. Not sure if this is down to the software version, account settings or what?

Example given is for a list of firewall rules:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules list
```

and the example output is

```
    NAME                         NETWORK      DIRECTION  PRIORITY  ALLOW                         DENY  DISABLED
default-allow-icmp           default      INGRESS    65534     icmp                                False
default-allow-internal       default      INGRESS    65534     tcp:0-65535,udp:0-65535,icmp        False
default-allow-rdp            default      INGRESS    65534     tcp:3389                            False
default-allow-ssh            default      INGRESS    65534     tcp:22                              False
dev-net-allow-ssh            dev-network  INGRESS    1000      tcp:22                              False
serverless-to-vpc-connector  dev-network  INGRESS    1000      icmp,udp:665-666,tcp:667            False
vpc-connector-egress         dev-network  INGRESS    1000      icmp,udp,tcp                        False
vpc-connector-health-check   dev-network  INGRESS    1000      tcp:667                             False
vpc-connector-to-serverless  dev-network  EGRESS     1000      icmp,udp:665-666,tcp:667            False
```

One rule per line with multiple fields horizontally. However, when I run this command in the Cloud Shell I get the following:

```
NAME: default-allow-icmp
NETWORK: default
DIRECTION: INGRESS
PRIORITY: 65534
ALLOW: icmp
DENY:
DISABLED: False

NAME: default-allow-internal
NETWORK: default
DIRECTION: INGRESS
PRIORITY: 65534
ALLOW: tcp:0-65535,udp:0-65535,icmp
DENY:
DISABLED: False

NAME: default-allow-rdp
NETWORK: default
DIRECTION: INGRESS
PRIORITY: 65534
ALLOW: tcp:3389
DENY:
DISABLED: False

NAME: default-allow-ssh
NETWORK: default
DIRECTION: INGRESS
PRIORITY: 65534
ALLOW: tcp:22
DENY:
DISABLED: False

NAME: fw-allow-health-check
NETWORK: default
DIRECTION: INGRESS
PRIORITY: 1000
ALLOW: tcp:80
DENY:
DISABLED: False

NAME: www-firewall-network-lb
NETWORK: default
DIRECTION: INGRESS
PRIORITY: 1000
ALLOW: tcp:80
DENY:
DISABLED: False
```

It's the same data but the layout is different. (Appreciate that output is not identical, but I'm ot concerned abiout that. Differences between sample and live data is ok here I think)

Now, you can change the output format with the format option, but I can't recreate this tab separated table.

Is this just down to the documentation reformatting the output? Is it down to the software version or a setting I've missed? Can the format option do this and I've just not figured it out?

Any pointers much appreciated, as it's frustrating me.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing you the best practices document [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/scripting-gcloud#best_practices), which explains the ways to format with example scripts.

You can check the possible outputs of --format in the [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/#--format) and also a similar thread [[SO link]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63867926/how-to-format-gcloud-compute-instances-list-output-to-excel-format) explains the ways to generate excel format output.

Answer (score 0):

@Richard Gieg has already provided a solution to this issue in this stack overflow discussion [Output of gcloud list commands not displaying in table form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70674544/12170358).

Setting the below flag will provide the table format that you are looking for.

```
gcloud config set accessibility/screen_reader false
```